# Non-triviality of the sum of simple rational functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, na.numerical-analysis

Recently, in the study of unicity problems in complex analysis, I met a problem that can be stated in the following way,

Let $\{m_i\}_{i=0}^{3}$ and $\{n_i\}_{i=0}^{3}$ be eight integers in $\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $m_i\neq n_i$ for $0\leq i\leq 3$.
Then
$$
R(z):=\sum_{i=0}^{3}(-1)^{i}\binom{3}{i}\frac{1-(\lambda_i z)^{m_i}}{1-(\mu_i z)^{n_i}}-\frac{1-(\lambda_{0}z)^{-m_0}}{1-(\mu_{0}z)^{-n_0}}
$$
is not identically to some constant for any non-zero $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_i$.

Of course, this may be checked using the computer in a very direct way. I wondered is there a nice way to discuss it by hands. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
& \mathbb Z \backslash\{0\} \\ {} \\
& \mathbb Z \setminus\{0\} \\ {} \\
& \mathbb Z \smallsetminus\{0\}
\end{align}
$$
The first line above uses `\backslash`, the second `\setminus` and the third `smallsetminus`. Those last two provide horizontal spacing proper to a binary operation symbol. I.e. we normally see $3+5$ and not $3{+}5$, whereas `+5` with nothing before it appears as $+5$ without that horizontal space (and similarly $3+$). The thing that makes you think one font looks good and another does not consists of many little things like this. $\qquad$

Comment: And that is why I edited the question as I did. The `\backslash`, causing you to see $\mathbb Z\backslash\{0\}$ instead of $\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ will strike people who are aware of things like this about the same way a spelling error does, and others will be affected in the way noted above, about differences between appearances of different fonts.

Comment: Remember that this software evolved ultimately from the work of the renowned software genius Donald Knuth, who explicitly intended to make attention to this kind of thing possible.

Comment: Given that $\frac{1-z^2}{1-z}-3\frac{1-z^3}{1-z}+3\frac{1-z^4}{1-z^2}-\frac{1-(-z)^2}{1-(-z)}-\frac{1-(-z)^2}{1-(-z)}\equiv -1$, you may want to revise your question and impose some more restrictions before any good answer to it can be given ;-)

Comment: @fedja Thanks for your comment, fedja. For the last term,  whether you mean $-\frac{1-z^{-2}}{1-z^{-1}}$, thanks.

Comment: @yaoxiao Nope, everything is as written, i.e., $m_0=-2, n_0=-1$. If you want to exclude negative numbers, you should say so explicitly in the formulation of the problem. As I said, some more restrictions can help, but we are not guessing which ones you really need :-)

Comment: @fedja thanks. It seems that $m_0$, and $n_0$ appear in the sum two times indeed, while, $m_i, _i (1\leq i\leq 3)$ appear only one time. And m_0, n_0 only appear one time in  the example above you mentioned.